# Python opencensus flask set request-id header as set in FlaskMiddleware/AzureLogHandler

Tags: python, azure, flask, azure-application-insights, opencensus

I'm using Azure Application Insights for my logging. I'm trying to set up an environment that all my logs have the same trace-id/request-id for visibility.

In the [documentation for logging requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/opencensus-python-request), by using the following code:

```
from flask import Flask
from opencensus.ext.azure.trace_exporter import AzureExporter
from opencensus.ext.flask.flask_middleware import FlaskMiddleware
from opencensus.trace.samplers import ProbabilitySampler

app = Flask(__name__)
middleware = FlaskMiddleware(
    app,
    exporter=AzureExporter(connection_string="InstrumentationKey=<your-ikey-here>"),
    sampler=ProbabilitySampler(rate=1.0),
)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='localhost', port=8080, threaded=True)
```

The request is being successfully logged in Azure Monitor with its request ID as operation_Id.

I can add logs with the same operation_Id with [traces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/opencensus-python#tracing), and I'll be able to see what traces were in some request:

```
from opencensus.ext.azure.trace_exporter import AzureExporter
from opencensus.ext.azure.log_exporter import AzureLogHandler
from opencensus.ext.flask.flask_middleware import FlaskMiddleware
from opencensus.trace.samplers import ProbabilitySampler
from opencensus.trace import config_integration
from opencensus.trace.samplers import AlwaysOnSampler
from opencensus.trace.tracer import Tracer

config_integration.trace_integrations(['logging'])
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s traceId=%(traceId)s spanId=%(spanId)s %(message)s')
tracer = Tracer(sampler=AlwaysOnSampler())

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.addHandler(AzureLogHandler(
    connection_string='InstrumentationKey=...')
)

app = Flask(__name__)
middleware = FlaskMiddleware(
    app,
    exporter=AzureExporter(connection_string="InstrumentationKey=..."),
    sampler=ProbabilitySampler(rate=1.0),
)
```

But how to write this trace-id that is logged in both requests and traces as a header to the user in the response?

Comment: Did you find a solution for it?
I can see that the entries in the request table has operation_Id and operation_ParentId
But logs in the traces table have these 2 missing :(